# Why does the test-connection command does not work and gives the below error

Tags: powershell

```
Test-Connection -ComputerName testserver.example.com -Count 1
Test-Connection : Provider load failure 
At line:1 char:1
+ Test-Connection -ComputerName testserver.example.com -Count 1
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidOperation: (:) [Test-Connection], ManagementException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : TestConnectionException,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.TestConnectionCommand
```

I removed -Count 1 then i got this

```
PS C:\Output_Monitors> Test-Connection -ComputerName testserver.example.com 
Test-Connection : 
At line:1 char:1
+ Test-Connection -ComputerName testserver.example.com
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidOperation: (:) [Test-Connection], COMException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : TestConnectionException,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.TestConnectionCommand
```

Then i did like this removing -ComputerName

```
PS C:\Output_Monitors> Test-Connection testserver.example.com
Test-Connection : Provider load failure 
At line:1 char:1
+ Test-Connection testserver.example.com
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidOperation: (:) [Test-Connection], ManagementException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : TestConnectionException,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.TestConnectionCommand
```

Comment: Related: [How can I resolve a “Provider load failure” for WMI requests?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/563150/3439404)

Comment: you should be able to find the information here: [https://devblogs.microsoft.com/scripting/use-powershell-to-troubleshoot-provider-load-failure/](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/scripting/use-powershell-to-troubleshoot-provider-load-failure/) and here: [https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/tn-archive/ee692772(v=technet.10)#EIAA](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/tn-archive/ee692772(v=technet.10)#EIAA)